# How to fix the view of admin all posts

Tags: wp-admin

This is how I see the admin view of all posts I need to fix that so that it will give a good view how can I do that? See the heading which came under custom side bar in that each line is one one letter i want it as a single line.

[image]

Comment: Is this WordPress.com or self-hosted? If self-hosted, how many plugins do you have active? What happens if you start deactivating them?

Comment: This is a wordpress self hosted website

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This obvious because WordPress post has 6 columns normally and you have 13.
However, the problem is title bar is getting squeezed. In latest version the column widths are like this:

***The Check box column:*** 2.2em ~ 3%
***The Title column:*** flexible as its width is default(auto)  (40% normally)
***The Author column:*** 10%
***The Categories column:*** 15%
***The Tags column:*** 15%
***The Comments column:*** 5.5em ~ 6.7%
***The Date column:*** 10%

### **Solution**

Add title width and specify a width but in em.

```
.column-title {
    width: 15em;
}
```

Adjust this value to get desired look.

### HOW TO APPLY

Use this code in your `function.php` file or you can implement this in side a custom plugin.
Here we have a small style script, in case you have more styles to add to admin back-end then add it using a custom css file.
**For small amount of script.**

```
function adjust_admin_style() {
  echo '<style>
    .column-title {
        width: 15em;
    }
  </style>';
}
add_action('admin_head', 'adjust_admin_style');
```

**Implement styles in large scales**

```
function prefix_admin_style() {

  wp_enqueue_style('admin-styles', get_template_directory_uri().'/yourstyle.css');

}
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'prefix_admin_style');
```

Comment: I have modified the ans follow the instructions above.

Comment: And the heading custom sidebar is not covered in this styling it will get pushed little side.